# terraform - variables root to child

Tags: variables, terraform

Currently I have the below structure in terraform. However I want to add a tfvars file given the environment but can not seem to find the best practice on how to do this.

If I want to add variables to all my modules given this set up.
So e.g. the variable tags with different values for dev and prod -> what would be the best practice to do this?

```
├── modules
│   ├── adf
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── variables.tf
│   └── storage
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       ├── variables.tf
├── dev
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
└── prod
    ├── main.tf
    ├── provider.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

Comment: "add a tfvars file given the environment" is there a reason you cannot use the normal method of one var file per environment and use it with the corresponding CLI arg? Is there some complexity or subtlety outside of the question?

Comment: adding a dev.tfvars fiel in dev folder and using terraform apply -var-file="dev.tfvars" does not work for me.

I feel like I need to specify these variables per module, but this is so redundant that it seems like I am missing something

Comment: Then your issue lies outside of the question content. You probably want to redo the question with information about your configs, expected results, and actual results so that we can assist you.

Comment: What's the difference between dev/main.tf and prod/main.tf - generally they should be common code with logic depending on the variables.